# What's with the extra threads reported by GDB?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, debugging, gdb

I have a C++ application that starts as single thread and processes some video frames. For each frame the application spawns 2 threads that join and this is done in a loop for each frame.

I'm trying to investigate whether there is another thread that I haven't detected. The application is quite complex and *loads shared libraries that may spawn threads of their own*.

I use **gdb's info threads** for that.

This is what I get:

```
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
  7    Thread 0x7fffde7fc700 (LWP 16644) "my_debugged_process" sem_wait ()
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sem_wait.S:85
  6    Thread 0x7fffdeffd700 (LWP 16643) "my_debugged_process" sem_wait ()
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sem_wait.S:85
  5    Thread 0x7fffdf7fe700 (LWP 16642) "my_debugged_process" sem_wait ()
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sem_wait.S:85
  4    Thread 0x7fffdffff700 (LWP 16641) "my_debugged_process" sem_wait ()
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sem_wait.S:85
  3    Thread 0x7fffe4988700 (LWP 16640) "my_debugged_process" sem_wait ()
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sem_wait.S:85
  2    Thread 0x7fffe5c0b700 (LWP 16639) "my_debugged_process" 0x00007ffff3dc812d in poll ()
    at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
* 1    Thread 0x7ffff7fc2800 (LWP 16636) "my_debugged_process" TheApplication::SomeClass::processFrame (this=0x743530, srcI=..., 
    dstI=...) at TheApplication.cpp:315
```

So the question is:

**What are the threads from 2 to 7? Are they somehow related to my process?** I only recognize thread 1.

I see that they are all waiting for a semaphore so I'm inclined to say that they belong to the debugger.

Comment: GDB does not usually start extra threads (at least not on GNU/Linux or other systems I've used). Print a stack trace for the other threads to see what code they are running, and whether you recognise it as your own program's code, e.g. `thread apply 2 where`

Comment: Or use `thread apply all bt` to see stack traces for all threads at once.

Comment: @ks1322 your suggestion and a little bit more debugging solved my problem. So in the end it is as Jonathan Wakely said: gdb does not create additional threads and the ones I'm seeing are related to my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what Jonathan said in the comments: on Linux, gdb does not create any threads in your process.  gdb tries to have a reasonably minimal impact on your application -- it can't be zero but it is pretty close.

Second, what Jonathan said again: to try to understand the threads after they are running, get a backtrace and see if it makes any sense.  For a single thread:

```
(gdb) thread 52  # e.g.
(gdb) bt
```

Or for all of them:

```
(gdb) thread apply all bt
```

Finally, to see threads when they are created, one way to try is to get a backtrace when the thread is started:

```
(gdb) break pthread_create
(gdb) commands
> bt
> cont
> end
```

This should print a stack trace when a thread is created.  This won't necessarily work in all cases (some programs call `clone` directly) but it should be ok for well-behaved libraries.